# How to get multiple Strings from .txt file

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Okay, so I'm trying to create a java program that will read a txt file and turn every line into a String. For example the txt file could be something like

```
 This should be a string
 This should be another string
 And another string
```

Currently my code only allows me to turn a txt file into one string.

```
 String Content = new Scanner(new File ("CONTENTS.txt")).useDelimeter(",").next();
 System.out.println(Content);
```

Comment: [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply but nextLine still seemed to only make the first line a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read [javadoc for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(fileName));
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  // process line here..
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems very helpful but I'm not going to be able to test it until tomorrow.